# Disable registry redirection to Wow6432Node in Python

Tags: python, windows, registry, wmi, winreg

I'm trying to access registry keys under HKEY_LOCAL_MAHINE\SOFTWARE... on a 64 bits system. I have following code but judging by the results it gets redirected to Wow6432Node even though I have *_winreg.DisableReflectionKey(_winreg.OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE"))* in my code.

```
import _winreg
import wmi

c = wmi.WMI(computer="localhost", namespace="root/default").StdRegProv

_winreg.DisableReflectionKey(_winreg.OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE"))

result, names = c.EnumKey(hDefKey=_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, sSubKeyName="SOFTWARE")

print names

_winreg.EnableReflectionKey(_winreg.OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE"))
```

I have read the following case but it seems that the solution described there doesn't work for either the author or for me:
[How can I turn off registry redirection on Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404595/how-can-i-turn-off-registry-redirection-on-python)

Also checked _winreg documentation, but there are no specific examples and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas? Sorry, I didn't have permission to comment in the existing case and had to open a new one.

Comment: Redirection is not the same as reflection. See the table [Registry Keys Affected by WOW64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384253%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Use the `access` flag `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` to disable redirection to `Wow6432Node`. You have to bitwise or it with the desired access, e.g. `KEY_ALL_ACCESS | KEY_WOW64_64KEY`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @eryksun ! worked like a charm :) I did the following:  

`handle = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Blabla\\blabla", 0, _winreg.KEY_READ | _winreg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY)`

Comment: But if you look at my code, I'm using c.EnumKey to get a list of all the registry keys under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SOFTWARE. Is it possible to do this iteration using KEY_WOW64_64KEY to avoid being redirected to wow6432node ?

Comment: Please disregard the previous question. I found the solution. Thanks for help!:)

Comment: If you found a solution using the wmi module, you should submit it as an answer. I don't see a way to do this using the WMI [`StdRegProv`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393664%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class.

Comment: There's [Requesting WMI Data on a 64-bit Platform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393067%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which shows setting a `__ProviderArchitecture` context, but I don't know how to configure that with the wmi module.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like "_winreg.KEY_READ | _winreg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY" does the job. To be more precise you need to open the key this way:

```
_winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE", 0, _winreg.KEY_READ | _winreg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY)
```

I got this working when accessing the localhost registry. However, I still haven't figured out how to connect to remote registry on the domain. Trying to use _winreg.ConnectRegistry, but keep getting access denied error.