# Opens same registry twice?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I am trying to get all installed programs of my windows computer, therefore I read out the registry.

But somehow python reads the 32bit programs out twice (even though I give him another registry entry)

Here is the code snipped:

```
def get_programs(registry):
    reg = ConnectRegistry(None, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
    programList = []

    key = OpenKey(reg, registry)
    print(QueryInfoKey(key))
    for i in range(0, QueryInfoKey(key)[0]):
        programList.append(EnumKey(key, i))
    CloseKey(key)
    CloseKey(reg)
    return programList
```

I call this function like this:

```
registry32bit = "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
registry64bit = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"    
programs32bit = get_programs(registry32bit)
programs64bit = get_programs(registry64bit)
```

Why does python open and read out the same registry (for 32 bit) twice and return the exactly same list?

Comment: you can use some debug tools like `pdb` or just simplely using `print`. Debug line by line to verify your code is working fine or not.

Comment: I already used the debug tool from pycharm :(

Comment: And?  Did you find anything?   This function `QueryInfoKey(key)` is called twice. Try to comment out `print(QueryInfoKey(key))`

Comment: No nothing, didn't change anything when I comment the print out. Don't know what I should change, since i am using _winreg library

Comment: It may have something to do with Windows' [registry reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) due to the fact you're running the 32-bit version of Python. See [_Disable registry redirection to Wow6432Node in Python_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280377/disable-registry-redirection-to-wow6432node-in-python).

Comment: @martineau, this is WOW64 registry redirection, not reflection. In Windows 7+ there is no reflection. Keys that used to be redirected and reflected in older versions are now either shared or just redirected. However, nothing has changed for `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`. This key has always been redirected to `SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\...` when running in the WOW64 subsystem.

Comment: Incidentally, explicitly using `Wow6432Node` is (technically) incorrect, as it depends on an implementation detail that is theoretically subject to change.  (In practice it is unlikely to do so, so you can probably get away with it.)  It is preferable to explicitly tell Windows whether you want the 32-bit view of the 64-bit view.

Comment: Have you actually looked at the contents of the two entries manually to make sure the two don't have the same contents?

Comment: @martineau, those two "Uninstall" keys are separate, which allows installing both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of a program. The OP is using 32-bit Python, so access is redirected. Accessing the native 64-bit view requires `KEY_WOW64_64KEY`. From a 64-bit process the 32-bit view requires `KEY_WOW64_32KEY`, and of course one can explicitly request either view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to work and uses @eryksun suggestion in a comment below about just letting the redirection happen and not explicitly referencing the `Wow6432Node` registry key. The central idea is to just specify either the `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` or `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` flag when opening the uninstall subkey and let the magic happen.

Note: I also *Pythonized* the code in the `get_programs()` function some. This made it shorter and more readable in my opinion.

```
import sys
from _winreg import *

# Assure registry handle objects with context manager protocol implemented.
if sys.version_info.major*10 + sys.version_info.minor < 26:
    raise AssertionError('At least Python 2.6 is required.')

def get_programs(subkey, regBitView):
    with ConnectRegistry(None, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) as hive:
        with OpenKey(hive, subkey, 0, regBitView | KEY_READ) as key:
            return [EnumKey(key, i) for i in range(QueryInfoKey(key)[0])]

UNINSTALL_REG_KEY = r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall'
programs32bit = get_programs(UNINSTALL_REG_KEY, KEY_WOW64_32KEY)
programs64bit = get_programs(UNINSTALL_REG_KEY, KEY_WOW64_64KEY)

print('32-bit programs:\n{}'.format(programs32bit))
print('')
print('64-bit programs:\n{}'.format(programs64bit))
```

Many thanks to @eryksun for the clues and many implementation strategy suggestions.

Comment: Just use `r"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"`. Allow the redirection filter to works its magic based on the flag in the desired access. The Windows I/O manager (i.e. devices and filesystems) and configuration manager (i.e. registry) are layered to allow filter drivers to modify operations on the fly. WOW64 has filter drivers in place for redirecting registry and filesystem access automatically. It's a different approach from how MultiArch is implemented on Linux because there's a problem with hard-coded paths in the Windows software jungle.

Comment: @eryksun: Good point (and explanation)—updated my answer accordingly. Thanks again.

Comment: winreg (or 2.x _winreg) keys are [already context managers](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v2.7.12/PC/_winreg.c#l582) (2.7.12 source) that support closing in a `with` block.

Comment: @eryksun: UFF...CWFL. Good to know—makes total sense—but since it's an unpublicized feature of the public API (so it's unknown how long it's been there), I'll leave the simple DIY helper function in my answer.

Comment: I suppose I should have linked to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/_winreg.html#_winreg.PyHKEY.__exit__) instead of the source. Context manager support was added in 2.6.

Comment: @eryksun: I suppose I should have checked the docs myself, instead of believing a comment in the source. Oh, well, answer updated yet again.