# How to make Python's winreg see entries in the registry that are visible in the Registry Editor for Adobe CC programs?

Tags: python, windows, adobe, winreg, adobe-cc

I am trying to use the `winreg` library of python to access the registry keys for Adobe products (Photoshop, After Effects, Ect.), and while i can see the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` subkeys in the Registry Editor, Python can't seem to see the same keys. Is there a permission that needs to be changed or am I approaching this the wrong way?

[Here is a Screen cap summarizing the results so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKELV.png)

The code I'm running to see this is:

```
import winreg
i=0
while True:
    try:
        # self.aeKey = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Adobe\\After Effects\\16.0")
        key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r"SOFTWARE\Adobe\Setup\Reader")

        printTest = winreg.EnumKey(key, i)
        print(printTest)
        i+=1
    except WindowsError:
        break
```

Which results in me having the return of

```
Acrobat Distiller
Acrobat PDFMaker
Adobe AIR
Adobe ARM
CommonFiles
ExtendScript Toolkit
ExtensionManager
PDF Admin Settings
Registration
Repair
Setup
```

But not

`Adobe Bridge`, `Adobe Acrobat`, `After Effects`, `Photoshop`, etc.

Edit: I'm Running 32-Bit Python currently.

Comment: Are you running 32- or 64-bit Python? Windows does some trickery when a 32-bit program tries to access certain things in the registry — something to with WOW (Windows on Windows). There are ways around it…

Comment: I am running 32 Bit Python, would love to know any ways around the 32/64 bit python wall, 

Specifically:
Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 22:45:29) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

Comment: I forgot to mention that it happens when running 32-bit Python on 64-bit Windows and is called "registry redirection". I'm certainly no expert on the topic — see the questions [Disable registry redirection to Wow6432Node in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280377/disable-registry-redirection-to-wow6432node-in-python). and [Opens same registry twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38703394/opens-same-registry-twice) for more info.

Comment: Thanks! will start looking into that direction!

Answer (score 2):

@martineau from the comments hit it right on the head! I needed to change the Access key in order to allow 64 bit registries to be found.

```
import winreg
i=0
while True:
    try:
        # self.aeKey = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Adobe\\After Effects\\16.0")
        key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r"SOFTWARE\Adobe",0, winreg.KEY_READ | winreg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY)
        assert key != None, "Key = None"
        printTest = winreg.EnumKey(key, i)
        print(printTest)
        i+=1
    except WindowsError:
        break
```

Now produces

```
Acrobat Distiller
Acrobat PDFMaker
Adobe Acrobat
Adobe Bridge
After Effects
Animate
Character Animator
CommonFiles
Dreamweaver 2020
Dreamweaver CC 2019
Identity
Licensing
Photoshop
Prelude
Premiere Pro
```

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Glad to hear you solved the problem and that my suggestions for more research were helpful — as well as for posting your solution for others.

Comment: Hi ApollosG, could you explain if the registry solution you found helped you getting any closer in using After Effects scripting in Python? Or was it for another purpose? Thank you!